# L-Tromino by using Tables with zero padding

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to display a L-Tromino.
L-tromino is a shape consisting of three equal squares joined at the edges to form a shape resembling the capital letter L.
I have tried

```
\begin{array}{cc} \square& \\ \square&\square\end{array}
```

but this contains paddings. How can I use zero padding for a 2x2 table?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: this appears similar to what's called "young tableaux".  the `youngtab` package (and others) may be helpful, although overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amssymb,tikz,graphicx}%  
\begin{document}

Using \verb|tabular|:
  \scalebox{.6}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c}\cline{1-1}
     & \\\hline
     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\\hline
  \end{tabular}} 
  Compare the size with that of \verb|\square| : $\square$

  Using \verb|TikZ| %% (just for fun as many of us are obsessed with tikz):
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,.5) -- (0,.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick] (0,.5) -- (0,1) -- (.5,1) -- (.5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: The size has been reduced using `\scalebox` from `graphicx`. In tikz, the option `scale` is used.

If you are using them frequently, you can define a macro as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amssymb,tikz,graphicx}% 
%
\newcommand{\Ltromino}{%
  \scalebox{.6}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c}\cline{1-1}
     & \\\hline
     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\\hline
  \end{tabular}}
  }
%
\newcommand{\LTromino}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,.5) -- (0,.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick] (0,.5) -- (0,1) -- (.5,1) -- (.5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\begin{document}
Using \verb|tabular|:

  \Ltromino

Compare the size with that of \verb|\square| : $\square$

Using \verb|TikZ|:

  \LTromino
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I decrease the table size so that a cell has a dimension as \square

Comment: @user706071: See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{array}{@{} c @{} c @{}} 
  \square & \\ 
  \square & \square
\end{array}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the additional spaces of the `array`/`tabular` can be minimized to zero:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}

$
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
  \square & \\
  \square & \square
\end{array}
$

\begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\mathsurround}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    $\square$ &\\
    $\square$ & $\square$
  \end{tabular}%
\endgroup

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{\textcolor{red}{$\square$}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with array/tabular]

But that does not solve your problems:

- The character box is larger than the character itself. The black `\fbox` frame is wider than the red `\sqare`. These white spaces are called left and right side bearings.
  The values of these are unkown in TeX.
- The upper line of the left lower box and the lower line of the upper box make a horizontal line with double line width. Also the line width of the glyph is not known in TeX.

Therefore I would do the drawing by graphics. An example for `tikz` that also allows rounded corners:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\squareunit
\newdimen\squarelinewidth 
\newcommand*{\BaseSquare}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \settoheight{\squareunit}{$\square$}%
    \setlength{\squarelinewidth}{.055\squareunit}%
    \addtolength{\squareunit}{-\squarelinewidth}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      x=\squareunit,   
      y=\squareunit,
      line width=\squarelinewidth,
      line join=round,
    ]
      \draw[line join=round]#1;%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \endgroup
}   
\newcommand*{\Square}{%
  \BaseSquare{(0,0) rectangle (1,1)}%
}

\newcommand*{\Ltromino}{%
  \BaseSquare{%   
    (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle
    (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0)
  }%
}   

\newcommand*{\ltromino}{%
  \BaseSquare{%
    (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,3) -- (0,3) -- cycle
    (0,1) -- (1,1)
    (0,2) -- (1,2)
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\square$\,\Square\,\Ltromino\,\ltromino

\end{document}
```

> [image: Trominos using tikz]